# If $X$ is a centered random variable and $C$ its covariance matrix then $P(X \in \mathrm{Im } C) = 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be an $m$-dimensional random variable and let $C$ be its covariance matrix. I am following a proof that says if $X$ is centered then $P(X \in \mathrm{Im } C) = 1$ where $\mathrm{Im } C$ is the image of $C$.

In the proof they show that for any $\xi$ in the kernel of $C$ we have
$$0 = \langle C\xi, \xi\rangle = E[\langle\xi, X\rangle^2]$$
and use the fact that since $C$ is symmetric its image coincides with the subspace of the vectors orthogonal to its kernel. Thus let $\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_k$, $k \leq m$, be a basis for the kernel of $C$. Thus
$$\{X \in \mathrm{Im } C\} = \{\langle X, \xi_1\rangle = 0\} \cap \cdots \cap \{\langle X, \xi_k\rangle = 0\}$$
and the proof is complete the proof because the right hand side is the intersection of a finite number of events with probability $1$.

I understand everything about this proof except for the last part. How do we know that $\{\langle X, \xi_i\rangle = 0\}$ has probability $1$ for $i \leq k$? Written more explicitly,
$$\{\langle X, \xi_i\rangle = 0\} = \{\omega \in \mathbb{R}^m : \langle X(\omega), \xi_i\rangle = 0\}.$$
For example, for elements $\omega$ in the nullspace of $C$ and for some $i$ it may be that $\langle X, \xi_i\rangle \neq 0$, and how can we say such events must have measure zero?

Comment: This follows from the first displayed equation $\mathbb{E}[\langle \xi_i, X \rangle^2] = 0$ (a non-negative random variable has expectation zero if and only if it is zero almost surely)

Comment: @JKL That was a lot simpler than I thought. Thank you.